# Интерфейсы в ООП (Java), по-простому?

Tags: ооп, java

Объясните по-простому, на пальцах, зачем и для чего нужны интерфейсы (Java)? Все эти заумные книжные определения и формулировки, ясности совсем не прибавляют.

Comment: Вопросом на вопрос: вы программируете без использования интерфейсов?

Comment: если трудно объяснить словами, можно на примере простого исходника.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Общее определение: 
Интерфейс — это совокупность методов и правил взаимодействия элементов системы. Другими словами, интерфейс определяет как элементы будут взаимодействовать между собой.

- Интерфейс двери — наличие ручки;
- Интерфейс автомобиля — наличие руля, педалей, рычага коробки передач;
- Интерфейс дискового телефона — трубка + дисковый набиратель номера.

Когда вы используете эти "объекты", вы уверены в том, что вы сможете использовать их подобным образом. Благодаря тому, что вы знакомы с их интерфейсом.

В программировании что-то похожее. Почему графическую часть программы часто называют интерфейсом? Потому, что она определяет каким образом вы сможете использовать основной функционал, заложенный в программе.

"Интерфейс определяет каким образом мы можем использовать объект" - перенесем эту мысль в плоскость программирования.

Предположим, у вас в программе есть следующие типы:

```
// несколько базовых интерфейсов, они пустые, 
// т.к. их наполнение на данный момент не существенно
interface Rul {}
interface Pedal {}
interface Kpp {}

// интерфейс описывает взаимодействие с автомобилем - т.е. его интерфейс
// предоставляет другим объектам доступ к рулю и педалям
// (по сути этот интерфейс соответствует автомобилю с коробкой автоматом)
interface Car {
  Rul getRul();
  Pedal[] getPedali();
}

// этот интерфейс расширяет базовый
// и предоставляет доступ еще и к коробке передач
interface CarWithKPP extends Car {
   Kpp getKpp();    
}

// а здесь у нас сам автомобиль
// реализации методов опущены т.к. не существенно
class SomeCar implements CarWithKpp {...}
```

а сейчас посмотрим, как можно пользоваться тем, что у нас есть:

```
// создаем новый объект
SomeCar instance = new SomeCar();

// делаем какие-то действия над объектом
testAction1(instance);
testAction2(instance);
```

Как видите, используем мы их одинаково, но суть кроется в реализации методов:

```
void testAction1(CarWithKpp c) {
   c.getRul(); // можно
   c.getPedali(); // можно
   c.getKpp(); // можно
}

void testAction2(Car c) {
   c.getRul(); // можно
   c.getPedali(); // можно
   c.getKpp(); // нельзя, ошибка компиляции. этот метод не определен в интерфейсе Car
}
```

С одной стороны, тот факт, что `SomeCar` наследует интерфейс `CarWithKpp` (а посредством последнего еще и `Car`), позволяет нам использовать его для работы с методами `testAction1, testAction2`. Интерфейсы, которые реализованы (имплементированы) в классе `SomeCar` — предоставляют доступ к правильному его использованию. А еще использование интерфейса в сигнатуре метода гарантирует, что вы получите именно тот тип, который вам нужен.

Обратная сторона медали состоит в том, что интерфейс накладывает ограничения на использование класса. Примером этому является то, что в методе `testAction2` получить доступ к методу `getKpp` уже невозможно. Таким образом, можно скрыть методы и свойства, которые объявлены в интерфейсе `CarWithKpp`, а также методы, объявленные в классе `SomeCar` (если их нет в интерфейсе). Оба метода могут использовать только тот набор "средств", которые им доступны (это определяется интерфейсом).

Comment: `Kpp` - это шикарно :)

Comment: ну так наверно автомат/неавтомат

Answer (score 10):

По простому говорите? Ну ок, правда сейчас тут начнут плеваться всякие товарищи типо гуру :)

Интерфейс - это возможность взглянуть на класс как на объект немного другого типа.

Поясню: ну как бы название говорит за это. Объект в ООП это некая сущность имеющая свой набор методов и работы с ним - методы назовем условно "воротами", а интерфейс это "дверь" в этих "воротах" - немножко другой способ обращения с тем же самым объектом. Так что если забыть про "ворота" то это кажется другим объектом. Ключевое слово здесь кажется.

Пример: есть объект стол, у которого есть методы работы с ним: как то есть поесть сидя за ним, накрыть на нем хавчик, поставить, собрать, отпилить ножки и проч. Но этот же объект стол можно рассматривать как интерфейс мебель (на языке ООП это называется класс типа стол реализующий интерфейс типа мебель: `class Table implements Furniture`. Понятно, что не на всякой мебели можно поесть или отпилить ножку, но что уж точно так это то что мебель можно поставить и собрать.

Теперь для чего все это нужно. Опять же пример с мебелью - если скажем есть объект стул, который также реализует интерфейс мебель, то и со стулом и со столом можно обращаться одинаково - в этом и состоит смысл интерфейса - **в унификации работы с разнотипными объектами**.

**P.S.** Кстати, любимый вопрос интервьюеров на собеседовании: что имеет более высокий уровень абстракции - класс, абстрактный класс или интерфейс? Правильный ответ - интерфейс

Comment: Розетка - это интерфейс

Comment: что-то вроде реализации полиморфизма?

Comment: Прочитал. Критикую. Пример с воротами - неудачный, со столом - плохой. Так как интерфейсы это больше как "набор правил/ рычагов воздействия на обьекты" одного типа, а у тебя примеры больше подходят к extened. У класса мебель могут быть свойтва - тип - дерево, пластик; высота, вес, цена, стул - наследник на 4х ножках, а у интерфейса для работы с мебелью методы типа - погрузить в машину, выкинуть, продать. Отсюда интерфейс - это розетка, за которой не видно как идет ток, какого он напряжения, как там провода перепутаны, но к нему всегда можно подключить любую технику

Comment: @Gorets ну я же говорил, что найдутся типо гуру с критикой :)

Comment: @Barmaley, с гуру-критиками - гениальный ход. Надо будет взять на вооружение.

Comment: @Barmaley, с воротами и дверями *в них* не очень удачно. Однако образ интересный.

Я бы по аналогии  сказал, что есть множество дверей в здании и "волшебные очки" (это интерфейс), которые показывают двери. Чтобы все заработало виртуальным (в очках) дверям должны соответствовать реальные. В то же время "лишние" реальные двери через очки не видны, но никому и не мешают. 

Плюс, через эти очки можно смотреть на разные здания.

Comment: ...а если принять таблеточку LSD - получится IoC контейнер.

Answer (score 10):

http://habrahabr.ru/post/30444/

Анонс:

Вам может показаться странным, но это именно то, что отличает человека от животного — использование интерфейсов вместо классов. Вы наверняка помните классический опыт с обезьяной, которую приучили гасить огонь водой из ведёрка; а потом поставили ведёрко на плот посреди бассейна, но обезьяна всё равно бегала по мостику на плот и черпала воду из ведёрка, вместо того, чтобы черпать воду прямо из бассейна. То есть обезьянка использовала класс Вода-в-Ведёрке вместо интерфейса Вода (и даже больше, скажу по секрету: вместо интерфейса Средство-для-Тушения).

Когда мы мыслим классами — уподобляемся животным. Люди мыслят (и программируют) интерфейсами.

Comment: Это правильный подход

(я про остальную часть статьи на хабре, а не мыслях о различии людей и животных).

Answer (score 8):

Понимание интерфейсов придёт со временем. Сколько не читай, сколько не объясняй, Вы Сами должны понять ту гибкость, тот масштаб действий, которые они предоставляют программисту. Пытайтесь их использовать. Библиотека классов Java предоставляет интерфейсы для реализации. Попробуйте их изучить, возможно это поможет Вам уловить всю мощь которую предоставляет программирование с использованием интерфейсов.

Answer (score 5):

Интерфейс - это описание того, что может и должен уметь делать объект класса, который реализует этот интерфейс.

Не будем оригинальны и возьмем для примера дверь.

Что обычный человек может сделать с дверью? Открыть и закрыть.

Соответственно интерфейс для нее будет такой:

```
interface Door{
    public boolean isClosed();
    public boolean open();
    public boolean close();
}
```

А теперь следите за руками. Объекту человек нужно пройти через дверь. Важно ему какая дверь перед ним дверь, деревянная, железная, с окошком, открывается она на себя или от себя, а может вообще сдвигается в бок? Нет, не важно. Ему важно, чтобы ее в принципе можно было открыть.

По этому, в классе "Человек" мы принимаем в метод "Пройти через дверь" не какую-то конкретную дверь, а в принципе "Дверь", потому что знаем, что у нее есть метод "Открыть".

```
class Human{
    public void goThruDoor(Door door){
        if(door.isClosed()){
            if(!door.open()){
                throw new Exception("дверь не открывается :(");
            }
        }
        goForward();
        door.close();
    }
}
```

Соответственно ниже пример двух объектов, реализующие интерфейс "Дверь" и которые можно передать "Человеку" в метод "Пройти через дверь", но реализующие разную логику для метола "Открыть".

```
class WoodenDoor implements Door{
    private boolean closed = false;
    public boolean isClosed(){
        return closed;
    }
    public boolean open(){
        if(!closed) return false;
        closed = false;
        return true;
    }
    public boolean close(){
        if(closed) return false;
        closed = true;
        return true;
    }
}

class LockedDoor implements Door{
    private boolean locked = true;
    private boolean closed = false;
    public boolean isClosed(){
        return closed;
    }
    public boolean open(){
        if(locked||!close) return false;
        closed = false;
        return true;
    }
    public boolean close(){
        if(closed) return false;
        closed = true;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Интерфейсом** объекта мы назовём набор
> операций (методов), которые он может
> совершать или которые можно совершать
> над ним. Например, интерфейс числа 3
> называется, собственно, «Число» и
> включает в себя набор операций
> сложения, вычитания, умножения и
> деления. Реализовать этот интерфейс
> может любое количество типов/классов,
> например, типы ЦелоеЧисло,
> ВещественноеЧисло, КомплексноеЧисло, а
> также такие неочевидные типы как
> Интервал или Полином. В то же время,
> один и тот же тип может реализовать
> более чем один интерфейс. Так,
> ЦелоеЧисло кроме интерфейса Число
> может реализовать интерфейс
> Перечислимый – для этого в классе
> ЦелоеЧисло будет необходимо всего лишь
> доопределить операции «следующий» и
> «предыдущий».

Comment: А где размещён при этом интерфейс ``Перечислимый``? В ``Число``?

Answer (score 3):

Представьте себе группу друзей. Все они люди и имеют свои особенности, профессии(кто-то шахтер, кто-то бармен и т.д.). Тут братва пришла в бар посидеть выпить пивка. А бар такой - если вы хотите быть клиентами бара - не вопрос реализуйте наш интерфейс "Клиент", и вот вам свод действий которые вы должны реализовать являясь клиентом: Купить пивко, сесть за стол, выпить пивко, заплатить счет. Все друзья разные, кто-то врач, кто-то сантехник, кто-то без руки, кто-то с татухой на лбу(странная компашка знаю)), но когда они приходят в бар - все они "клиенты" и обязаны реализовать интерфейс "Клиент" с его методами. Да, каждый из них реализует, интерфейс по своему - кто-то даст на чай, когда будет оплачивать счет, кто-то разобьет бутылку об лоб, когда будет пить пивко ну и т.д.(это уже полиморфизм), но все они клиенты в данный момент и сотрудники бара взаимодействуют с ними как с клиентами, а не Васей(шахтером), Петей(алкоголиком). и.д.
В общем интерфейсы нужны, что бы связать группу не связанных объектов, которые обязаны реализовать поведение того интерфейса, что бы можно было взаимодействовать с ними через этот общий интерфейс.

Answer (score 2):

Объясню без деталей.

Допустим, мы создали *Framework*, который определяет, совершил ли пользователь `double-click` по экрану.

Там мы определили функцию: `что_делать_если_пользователь_кликнул_2_раза_по_экрану()`.

Но мы решаем не определять поведение этой функции сами, а предоставить эту реализацию программисту, использующему наш фреймворк. Предоставление этой реализации можно сделать через механизм интерфейсов.

Функцию: `что_делать_если_пользователь_кликнул_2_раза_по_экрану()` засовываем в интерфейс.

И, таким образом, сам момент двойного клика по экрану определяет наш фреймворк, а вот что делать (рисовать звездочки на экране, запустить проигрывание музыки и т.д.) после этого события решает программист, который реализует наш интерфейс.

Польза: программисту не надо думать, как словить `double-click`. За ним только реализация ответа на это событие.

Answer (score 2):

"зачем и для чего":

1) Взаимодействие с окружающим миром. Программы пишет не один человек, они состоят не из одного класса и зачастую не из одного пакета и модуля. И суть программы в том, что код разных авторов, разных модулей взаимодействует между собой. Самый простой пример: вы пользуетесь сторонними библиотеками. Вы нашли нужный вам класс, подключили библиотеку, которая его содержит и вызываете оттуда методы. В какой-то момент автор библиотеки решил изменить свой код, разве это редкость? Исправить выявленные баги, улучшить, расширить функционал. И это может оказаться для вас глубокой неожиданностью: ваш-то код завязан на его код! И ваш код внезапно ломается.

Чтобы такого не происходило, чтобы чужой открытый код мог использоваться сторонними разработчиками без неожиданностей, придумали интерфейсы. **Интерфейс — это объявление функционала. Имплементация классом интерфейса — это гарантия реализации функционала.** Если класс имплементирует некоторый интерфейс, то он обещает, что в нем есть объявленные в интерфейсе методы, они принимают объявленные параметры и возвращает объявленное значение.
У вас может возникнуть вопрос: но ведь интерфейсы — это тоже код и его так же, как и класс, можно изменить. Можно. Но на практике это происходит крайне редко, интерфейс - это заявленный контракт и мы понимаем, что наш интерфейс, если он открыт, может использоваться не только нами.

2) В Java в качестве ссылки на переменную может выступать интерфейс. Например, уместен следующий метод:

```
public void letsIterateABit(Iterable something){ //Iterable — это  интерфейс, у которого есть метод iterator(). 
    //какой-то код
    something.iterator();
    //еще какой-то код
}
```

В этот метод можно передать любой объект которые имплементирует интерфейс Iterable. Конечно, и вызывать в этом случае мы у него сможем только те методы, которые есть в интерфейсе. Но иногда этого более чем достаточно!

3) Интерфейсы позволяют реализовывать [инверсию зависимостей](https://habr.com/ru/post/313796/). *Если вы разобрались в первых двух пунктах, но не разобрались в этом — у вас все хорошо, вернитесь перечитать статью через полгода.*

Answer (score 1):

Если вы знакомы со схемотехникой, электроникой, то интерфейс подобен мультиплексору - один выход и много входов.

Или другая аналогия. Револьвер с барабаном. В барабане патроны (имплементация) подаются в канал ствола (интерфейс).

В общем, это способ передачи классов  по унифицированному каналу (от имени интерфейса - полиморфизм) в другой класс. Таким образом можно обеспечить множественное наследование. Интерфейс позволяет при проектировании определить стандарт взаимодействия объектов. При этом меняя(улучшая) реализацию интефейсов, вы не трогаете сам стандарт. Это удобно. Можно сказать, что это абстрагирование описания от реализации.

Comment: Аналогии - такие аналогии. Канал ствола - это принимающий класс (один из них), но никак не интерфейс: патрон не реализует интерфейс "канал ствола", а реализует интерфейс "патрон".

Comment: Канал ствола - это принимающий класс

Да, можно, конечно, и так сказать -  у разных людей срабатывают разные аналогии. Мне удобнее именно так. Если мы представим внешнюю среду (куда вылетает пуля), то канал ствола будет именно интерфейсом. Я вообще не видел нормального выражения этого понятия - обычно объяснения тонут в деталях и "программизмах".  Мне лично близок пример мультиплексора т.к. ни одно из объяснений не помогло - сказывается прошлый опыт, увы. Поэтому для себе нарисовал схемку: https://github.com/TarasPlakhotnichenko/JavaInterfaces/blob/master/java_interface.pdf

Comment: Или другая аналогия - компьютер.  В кресло перед компьютером присаживаются разные люди. Они что-то делают на этом компьютере,  общаясь в чате и  посылая сообщения, сменяя друг друга за компьютером. Люди меняются, но интерфейс остается тем же самым - это компьютер. Чтобы воспользоваться чатом, надо использовать интерфейс - компьютер. Эти люди должны уметь пользоваться компьютером - имплементация интерфейса.

Comment: Это все прекрасно, но к интерфейсам в Java не имеет отношения.

Comment: Предложите свой вариант, я же не против.  Вам вот кажется, что не имеет, а  кому-то  все объяснит.

Comment: Интерфейс - это характеристика самого объекта, а не объекты с которыми он может взаимодействовать. Патрон наследуются от абстрактного класса боеприпас (если объект с одной стороны ударить, с другой стороны вылетит снаряд) и реализует интерфейс "цилиндр" (конечно его форма несколько сложнее, но сейчас это не принципиально). Ствол реализует интерфейс "круглое отверстие", через которое с одинаковым успехом может пройти и пуля, и шомпол, и всякий мусор можно напихать.

Comment: Теперь "магазин патронов" - в реальности это контейнер (фактически, стек) цилиндров, он может наследоваться от, например `Stack<Cylinder>`. `Stack` - абстрактный класс, `Cylinder` - интерфейс. По сути в него можно зарядить и патроны, и просто цилиндры подходящего размера (можно карандаш например напилить). Конечно же, в программе для данного случая лучше использовать не интефейс формы, а абстрактный класс конкретного типа патронов, чтобы нельзя было зарядить пистолет карандашами, но для реального мира это "прокатит". Правда пистолет стрелять не будет.

Comment: И еще раз, ложе, магазин, барабан револьвера - не являются интерфейсами патрона, а являются отдельными классами, поддерживающими этот интерфейс.

Answer (score 1):

**Интерфейс** - это обещание реализации методов в структурированном виде.

Обещанные в интефейсе методы нужно реализовывать в классах.

Примеры интерфейсов:

1. Интерфейс смартфона, в нем мы говорим что у объекта смартфон обязательно будет метод вес.

```
public interface Smartphone {
    public int weight();
}
```

2. Для NFC модуля мы создали отдельный интерфейс, чтобы не обещать реализовывать данный метод в каждом смартфоне. Мы ведь за словами следим.

```
public interface NfcModule {
    public boolean use();
}
```

Реализация в классе

```
public class SmartfoneMotorolla implements Smartphone, NfcModule {
    @Override
    public int weight() {
        //200 грам вес смартфона
        return 200;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean use() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Интерфейсы являются основой взаимодействия всех современных информационных систем. Если интерфейс какого-либо объекта (персонального компьютера, программы, функции) не изменяется (стабилен, стандартизирован), это даёт возможность модифицировать сам объект, не перестраивая принципы его взаимодействия с другими объектами (так, например, научившись работать с одной программой под Windows, пользователь с легкостью освоит и другие — потому, что они имеют однотипные элементы интерфейса).

Пример с программами Windows очень понятен)) я сам сюда зашел чтобы понять что такое интерфейс

Comment: Вы рассказали про интерфейсы, но не дали определение. Если читатель не знает, что это такое, он продолжит не знать.

Answer (score 0):

По-простому. Вопрос со множественным наследованием во многих языках программирования решается просто - либо разрешить, либо запретить. Джависты решили сесть на оба стула и выбрали свой, особый путь. Джава, в принципе, не умеет в множественное наследование классов. Если мы пишем ключевое слово `extends`, то мы знаем, что наследовать мы будем только один класс, будь он абстрактным или обычным. Но дабы упростить проектировку и обеспечение совместимости, плюшки от множественного наследования тоже хочется иметь, и тут на сцене появляются интерфейсы. Интерфейс - это список методов (только `public`(даже слово это писать не надо, в интерфейсе других быть не может), и только БЕЗ реализации) и переменных, которые обязательно, ну вот по любому есть в классе-потомке. И вот интерфейсов как раз через ключевое слово implements можно пихать сколько угодно. И друг от друга их наследовать можно. Таким образом, интерфейс - это гарантия того, что классы, реализующие его, содержат методы и переменные, в нем перечисленные. Потому, выражение `ourObject instanseof ourInterface` возвращает истину, мы точно знаем, что в `ourObject` есть методы, перечисленные в `ourInterface`

Comment: Какой-то холивар на тему стульев и особого пути. А суть в последних двух предложениях.

Comment: `и только БЕЗ реализации` а как же реализация по умолчанию?

Comment: Подтверждаю неточность. В java8 можно делать default-реализации в теле интерфейса, тогда в самих implements-классах можно вообще не реализовывать метод, а использовать default-реализацию из интерфейса.

Comment: Кстати в C# то же самое.

Answer (score 0):

Мне понравилось определение на JavaRush:
В более широком смысле интерфейс какой-нибудь вещи – это механизм взаимодействия этой вещи с другими предметами. Например, пульт от телевизора – это дистанционный интерфейс. Собака понимает и исполняет команды — это значит, что собака поддерживает голосовой интерфейс (управления). Если все это подытожить, то можно сказать, что интерфейс – это стандартизированный способ взаимодействия двух вещей, и этот стандарт известен двум сторонам. Когда человек говорит собаке «сидеть», он отдает команду в соответствии с «голосовым интерфейсом управления собакой», и если собака выполняет эту команду, то мы говорим, что собака поддерживает этот интерфейс.

Так же и в программировании. Методы – это действия над объектом, над его данными. И если класс реализует определенные методы, то он «поддерживает исполнение» определенных команд.

Answer (score -1):

> Интерфейсы предназначены для поддержки динамического разрешения вызовов
>   методов во время выполнения. Как правило, для нормального выполнения
>   вызова метода из одного класса в другом оба класса должны присутствовать во время
>   компиляции, чтобы компилятор Java мог проверить совместимость сигнатур
>   методов. Само по себе это требование создает статическую и нерасширяемую среду
>   распределения классов. В такой системе функциональные возможности неизбежно
>   передаются вверх по иерархии классов, в результате чего механизмы будут
>   становиться доступными все большему количеству подклассов. Интерфейсы предназначены
>   для предотвращения этой проблемы. Они изолируют определение метода
>   или набора методов от иерархии наследования. А поскольку иерархия интерфейсов
>   не совпадает с иерархией классов, то классы, никак не связанные между
>   собой иерархически , могут реализовать один и тот же интерфейс. Именно в этом
>   возможности интерфейсов проявляются наиболее полно.

245 страница, глава 9 "пакеты и интерфейсы", Java 8 Полное руководство. Шилдт. 2015 г.

Comment: Цитирую автора вопроса: `Все эти заумные книжные определения и формулировки, ясности совсем не прибавляют`.

Comment: Слишком сложно для понимания написано. Люди приходят на stackoverflow.com не за цитатами из книг, а за внятными ответами на свои вопросы))

Answer (score -6):

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
set = new TreeSet<String>();
HashSet<String> newSet = new TreeSet<String>(); // - impossible
```

Интерфейс в java определяет интерфейс класса. Непонятно становится из-за несовершенности технического русского в программировании. Для более общего понимания нужно уяснить значения слова интерфейс.

Comment: Отличный пример определения термина через этот же термин. Так делать не нужно, потому что такое определение бессмысленно.