# не могу вывести данные через hibernate когда прописываю @Transactional выдаёт ошибку

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

вот ошибка

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'catTestDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'catTestDaoImpl' is expected to be of type [com.websimba.spring.beans.CatTestDaoImpl] but was actually of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5179)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1702)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:431)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'catTestDaoImpl' is expected to be of type [com.websimba.spring.beans.CatTestDaoImpl] but was actually of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.checkBeanNotOfRequiredType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1480)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1459)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566)
    ... 60 more
```

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
      p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
      p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" p:username="root" p:password="root" />

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <!--<property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />-->
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.spring.model" />
    <!--<property name="annotatedPackages" value="com.websimba.spring.model"/>-->
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect" >org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql" >true</prop>
            <prop key="current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
            <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

в классе

```
@Component
public class CatTestDaoImpl implements CatTestDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Transactional
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Categories> listCat() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Categories").list();
    }
}
```

в контролере

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private CatTestDaoImpl catTestDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Map<String,Object> map){
        map.put("Categories", new Categories());
        map.put("CategoriesList",catTestDao.listCat());
        return "home";
    }
}
```

в чём может быть проблема или что я делаю неправильно ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Неправильно то, что вы пытаетесь за-autowire-ить конкретную реализацию интерфейса `CatTestDao`.

С технической точки зрения, проблема возникает из-за того, как Spring обрабатывает транзакции. Для того, чтобы иметь возможность прозрачно для разработчика открыть и закрыть транзакцию, Spring при инициализации компонента создаёт [proxy-объект](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)). Этот объект реализует те же интерфейсы, что и исходный компонент. Proxy-объект позволяет Spring'у выполнить какой-то код до/после/вместо кода метода исходного класса. В случае с управлением транзакциями - открыть транзакцию, выплнить код вашего метода, затем закрыть транзакцию, если метод выполниля успешно, или откатить её в противном случае.

Складывается такая ситуация: инициализируя `CatTestDaoImpl`, Spring создаёт вместо него объект класса `Proxy`, который реализует интерфейс `CatTestDao`. А `HomeController` требует объект класса `CatTestDaoImpl`. Так как такого объекта в контейнере Spring'а нет, инициализация падает. Для того, чтобы всё заработало, нужно в `HomeController`'е autowie-ить `CatTestDao`, а не `CatTestDaoImpl`, тогда созданный Spring'ом proxy-объект будет распознан как кандидат на autowire-инг.

С идеологической точки зрения, обращение к интерфейсу, а не к конкретной его реализации, делает программу слабо связной (loose coupled). Это позволяет при необходимости заменять реализации интерфейсов без модификации кода, который их использует. Например, вы могли бы подсунуть вашему `HomeController`'у реализацию `CatTestDao`, получающую данные не из БД, а, например, через REST API, и `HomeController` не заметил бы разницы. Почитайте ответы на [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/136909/5577), там очень подробно объясняется преимущество.