# Переопределение метода, Override

Tags: java, override

Надо искать пересечения множеств. У каждого класса есть метод добавляющий элемент, метод выводящий содержание класса на экран.И другие. А как сделать чтоб был один метод addElement который бы в зависимости от класса добавлял в одном случае Interval,в другом случае IntervalSet, или allIntervalSet
Точно так же одно название метода вывода на экран например convertToString.
Оверрайд короче.
Спасибо.

Класс interval описывает 1 интервал например
  [-5;8]

```
 public class Interval {
  public Double from;
  public Double to;
  public Interval(Double from, Double to) {
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
  }
public void convertIntervalToString(){ 

    System.out.print("["+this.from+" ; "+this.to+"]");
}   
public void putFrom(Double x) { 
    this.from = x;
}
public void putTo(Double x) { 
    this.to = x;
}

}
```

Класс IntervalSet задает 1 множество любой длины
 [-7;-6][-5;0][1;2]

```
public class IntervalSet {
private  ArrayList<Interval> intervalSet;
public IntervalSet() {
    this.intervalSet = new ArrayList<Interval>();
}

public void convertIntervalSetToString(){
    int i = this.intervalSet.size();
    if (i == 0){ 
        System.out.println("[Пустое множество]"); 
    };
    for (int j=0; j<i; j++) 
        this.intervalSet.get(j).convertIntervalToString();
    System.out.println("");
}
 public void addInterval(Interval x){
    this.intervalSet.add(x);
  }//add() это метод java
```

Класс allIntervalSet задает несколько математических множеств

[-9;-8][-7;0][1;7][][][]

[][][][][]

[-9;9]

[-8;0][][][][][]

[][][][][]

```
public class AllIntervalSet {
private  ArrayList<IntervalSet> allIntervalSet;
public AllIntervalSet() {
    this.allIntervalSet = new ArrayList<IntervalSet>(); 
}
public void convertAllIntervalSetToString(){
    int i = this.allIntervalSet.size();
    for (int j=0; j<i; j++) 
        allIntervalSet.get(j).convertIntervalSetToString();
}
public void addIntervalSet(IntervalSet x){
    this.allIntervalSet.add(x);
}
}
```

Comment: Этот метод `addElement`, он в каком классе должен быть, во всех трёх или как? И, возможно, стоит написать [интерфейс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/137018/227016), от которого все три класса будут наследоваться.

Comment: К каждому классу нужно уметь добавлять элемент, и уметь выводить каждый класс на экран.

Comment: Отлично. Прочитали про интерфейсы по ссылке? Создаёте интерфейс, в нём будет метод `convertToString`. Наследуете все три класса от этого интерфейса. Меняете названия методов для вывода во всех трёх классах на `convertToString`. И вот в каждом классом есть метод, который, грубо говоря, является `override` для метода интерфейса